# Dynamic Order For Model Fields In Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    item1 = models.ForeignKey(Item1)
    item2 = models.ForeignKey(Item2)
```

I want to give dynamic order to this model:

```
item1 -> order2, item2 -> order1
```

and this may changeable by user in Django admin. How can I do this in Django admin?

Answer (score 1):

In the model, the ordering you define is the default ordering (for queries that do not specify their own order_by). So if you need several sort order, you will need to define those for each of the queries, using the q.order_by(...) function.

Comment: But how admin user could dynamically change the order?